# how to handle touch events in IOS/Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ios, mobile-safari

I am working on a web application. As per the requirement i need to create scrolling images effect when user swipe and on touch (or click) i need to move the specific image to some predefined destination.

So some stack of images has two events, on touch move it should scroll left or right and on touch start(click) it should move to some distance.

I am unable to handle both events, i want to fire only touch-move event when user swipe and want touch-start to fire when user touch or click.

But on swiping, touch start event is also firing up. Please advice me the solution.

Even i have tried click event instead of touch start but still i have same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at **[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)**. Although it is in Alpha stage right now they are planning to release the first version in spring 2011.

> **jQuery Mobile: Touch-Optimized Web Framework for Smartphones & Tablets**
>
> A unified user interface system across
> all popular mobile device platforms,
> built on the rock-solid jQuery and
> jQuery UI foundation. Its lightweight
> code is built with progressive
> enhancement, and has a flexible,
> easily themeable design
>
> **Touch-optimized layouts & UI widgets**
>
> Our aim is to provide tools to build
> dynamic touch interfaces that will
> adapt gracefully to a range of device
> form factors. The system will include
> both layouts (lists, detail panes,
> overlays) and a rich set of form
> controls and UI widgets (toggles,
> sliders, tabs)

Demos are **[here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/)**.

Comment: These solutions look pretty good. Thanks for sharing. However i already wrote scrolling script and did all other coding as well. At this point of time, i am looking for some solution to tackle the touch event separately. Like how to differentiate between touch start and touch move. So that when user swipe i will fire a event and when user touch i will fire some b event. Please advice

Comment: as per the research i got to know that, we can able to calculate number of touches and from there we can throw the events depending on the touches, like if touches are less than 10 pixel- touch start or if more than 10 pixel it should be touch move. But not getting exact way to accomplish this. Please help

Comment: Jquery Mobile is a pretty awful framework if you're trying to build rich client applications.  It's really designed to make old server-side-rendered PHP/ASP/JSP apps feel like native apps, but the end result is pretty crappy.  If you're trying to use any modern web development techniques, use Zepto, Spine, or something else for your tap events.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at YUI 3's Scrollview widget at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/scrollview/
Also, YUI 3.2 added touch support.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to swap out Jquery for something a little smaller and a little more mobile-friendly, [Zepto](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto) provides a pretty decent alternative.  It's not a drop-in replacement for everything Jquery, but it is surprisingly compatible.  It provides basic touch events and CSS animations to make modern web development possible on iOS.

If you're looking for a more complete mobile framework, [Spine.js](http://spinejs.com/) and [Spine.Mobile.js](http://spinejs.com/mobile/docs/index) sit on top of either Jquery or Zepto, and works very nicely for creating single-page-apps using modern JS development techniques.

[IScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) also does a nice job of hiding the pain of touch events, and makes things like static headers and footers possible, even in older versions of iOS and Android.

### UPDATE

`jqTouchPunch` is a bit of a hack, but works surpisingly well...